# How we change text of custom button depending upon the value which is occurred on dice?

Tags: iphone, ios

i am having dice values from 1 to 6. 
and also i'm having Alphabets from A to Z.

at the time of application loading i set the title of that custom button to "A".
when i click on the dice a random number will generated i.e for suppose here it is 5

now my task is change the title/text of the custom button to "F" means 5 increments from A.

and also when the text is "Z" when i click on the dice if i get 4 now my output would be "D"

how i can achieve these two tasks?

Comment: You have to manage this calculation by your self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way...

```
Array *a=[[NSArray arraywithObjects:@"A",@"B",........@"Z",nil];
 first DiceNumaber=1;

Then Random Number=5;

DiceNumber=DiceNumber+5;
//So, DiceNumber=6;




   Then
   if(DiceNumber>26){
 DiceNumber=DiceNumber%26;
}

Now, lblText.text=[a objectAtIndex:DiceNumber - 1];
//This will prints "F"
```

**Let me know if you have any Problem.**

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can work with ASCII values and NSString. Note that since NSString is working with unichars, there could be unexpected results for a non ASCII string.

First you have to take the ascii value of the current alphabet. Assume your current alphabet is A. then it's ascii value is:

```
 // NSString to ASCII
  NSString *string = @"A";
  int asciiCode = [string characterAtIndex:0]; // 65
```

Now roll the dice and you get the dice value 5 then add 5 to ascii value:

```
So, current asciiCode= asciiCode + 5; //70
// ASCII to NSString
// int asciiCode = 70;
if(asciiCode<91)
{
       NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", asciiCode]; //E
}
else
{
      int remainder = 90%asciiCode;
      NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 65 + remainder-1];
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction) buttonAction: (UIButton *) sender
{
    int offset = arc4random() % 6 + 1;
    char currentTitle = (sender.titleLabel.text.length > 0) ? [sender.titleLabel.text characterAtIndex: 0] : 'A';
    char nextTitle = 'A' + (currentTitle - 'A' + offset) % ('Z' - 'A');
    [sender setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%c", nextTitle] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason for downvoting? I've tested this solution and it works.